# Debug CreateML Documentation

Tags: debugging, createml

Ive trained a couple action classifier models, and a few object detection models with no issues. Recently tho everything started crashing, not sure why, i have not updated anything on my computer. Does anybody know how to debug the application? I've been looking for documentation, however I have not been able to find any info that would help me debug common errors. More info below on issues i've had.

I am having multiple issues depending on what I am trying to train. I have another question open for an ioaf code error. While waiting on response, i started working on another model, on a different laptop. This model is to recognize users action. However, this one is now failing with "asset contains no video tracks". this is not making any sense, to me. I am unable to find any documentation to debug or read any error logs from CreateML, and their technical support is no support.

Has anybody run into a similar issue, or know how to debug the application? Im trying to figure out where its failing, i've opened several of the video files to see if they are corrupted and so far none have been. This is not a good debug method for small teams and your dealing with hours of video clips or thousands of images.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have this issue when some python libraries be updated and change import things, like the imput structure. So check this. I reccommend you to upload your errors in order to help you. Try also to work on other editor like google colab, but not that there every variable is global.

Comment: Im using Apples CreateML app to train the models. I am not given enough information to debug, i get stuff like

**internal error (ioaf code 1)** - appears to be an issue with cpu and ram, but cant conclude
**asset contains no video tracks** - finnaly found issue with clip somewhere in 300's.

my main concern is in finding the error logs, or getting more info from apple.

Comment: i will be moving to somethign like tensorflow or keras, but im trying to get a POC first.